# selective python ODE solver outputs

Tags: python, ode

I am using the scipy.integrate to solve a system of ODEs. An abstract of my code looks like this:

```
# step 1: import all necessary modules and functions imports here
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import ode

# step 2: define ode sys  
def ode_rhs(t, y, p1, p2, ..., pn):   
  ''' do some stuff to define rhs''' 
  return ydot

# step 3: set parameters p1, p2, ..., pn 
"""
p1 = ...
p2 = ...
...
pn = ...
"""

# step 4: set time parameters
ts = 0.0
tf = 340.

# step 5: set initial conditions
y0 = np.zeros(some_shape) 

# step 6: set ode solver
#backend = 'dopri5'
backend = 'vode'
r = ode(ode_rhs).set_integrator(backend, method='BDF', atol=1e-12, rtol=1e-6)
r.set_initial_value(y0,ts)

# step 7: store solution
t   = [ts]
y  =  [y0]

# step 8: call ode rhs and integrate
while r.successful() and r.t < tf:
  r.set_f_params(p1, p2, ..., pn)
  r.integrate(tf, step=True)

  t.append(r.t)  
  y.append(r.y)  

# step 9: process output for plotting
t   = array(t)
y = array(y).T
```

The solver outputs values of y at whatever timesteps it uses to advance the solution. What I need is outputs at specific times (0, 1, 2, ... 339) not at timesteps used internally by the solver. I could have used the r.integrate(t+dt). However, I have to use variable stepping to reduce simulation time.

Comment: could you kindly supply us with a minimal, executable example? Especially `ode()` comes from nowhere, does it belong to `scipy` or something else?

Comment: Could you interpolate between the solver timesteps to get others?

Comment: @Faultier: apology for the incompleteness. I could not post the executable code because of the many dependencies on other user-defined functions and ext. files associated with it. I have updated my post to show where the solver is coming from.

Comment: @Paul: I would like the solver to solve at these particular times, for which I have validation data. My system if very dynamic, and I don't know if interpolation is appropriate. In case I would like to interpolate, I guess I will have to do this after having solved the system (i.e. on y), right?

Comment: Why not just run ``integrate()`` for each of the time periods between samples and collect the final results of each of such runs?

Comment: I just quickly read through the the descriptions - it seems that `scipy.integrate.odeint` does what you need. I cannot say anything about the performance though; but you could "choose" start values by abusing `scipy,integrate.ode`, thus finally yielding y at your desired t.

Comment: @user2624750: yes what I suggested would only work after having first solved the system on y.  And you are correct, interpolation may or may not be appropriate.